# Filter top questions of the month by ...err... month?

Tags: discussion, filtering, top-questions

If I'm looking at the [top questions for the month](https://stackoverflow.com/?tab=month), it's actually showing me the top questions for the past 30ish days. Is there a way to actually filter this on a month to month basis (ie. May, June, July, etc).

I know I could always use the API and filter based on start and end timestamp for any given month/year combo, but I feel like "Top Questions of the Month" is kind of deceiving if its really based on days instead of the standard calendar.

Comment: This is of course a feature, not a bug.  It would make the list pretty useless for the first several days of a month.

Comment: I never tagged it as a bug. If there was a way to filter by month you could look at past months too which would be useful